# Xamarin Forms: Setting app language independently from OS settings

Tags: c#, android, ios, localization, xamarin

Out client wants the language of the app we are developing to be configurable independently from the OS settings. I've started by setting up localization using this how-to: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/ This works fine.

Now I'm trying to set the CurrentUICulture (or equivalent) in all three apps, from the app's stored settings. I've expanded the ILocalize interface to allow for setting, and WinPhone is no problem, but Android and iOS are having me scratching my head.

This is the android code.

```
public class Localize : AppResources.ILocalize
{
    public CultureInfo CurrentUICulture
    {
        get
        {
            var androidLocale = Locale.Default;
            var netLanguage = androidLocale.ToString().Replace("_", "-"); // turns fi_FI into fi-FI

            return new CultureInfo(netLanguage);
        }

        set
        {
            var locale = value.ToString().Replace("-", "_");

            Locale.Default = new Locale(locale);
        }
    }
}
```

It partially works, but for some reason unknown to me, only some of the resource strings are translated (maybe the ones set in xaml?).

In iOS, I have no idea how to set the locale.

Any pointers? Any better ideas? Only using the phone's language is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS I managed to set the CultureInfo like this:

```
        CultureInfo newCulture = // whatever :)
        // make sure the following is executed on the UI thread
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

This affects string formatting of DateTime and so on, but not the look of native controls, like the date format of a date picker.

Comment: And how can I save it? I have to save the culture info because otherwise the user has to change the language everytime when he is using the app...

Comment: You would need to store the user's selected value and set the culture on every startup. For example you could store and load the culture-code in Xamarin.Forms' "Properties Dictionary": https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary